# Export a polygon shapefile as a list of XY vertex pairs

Tags: r, r-sf

For a contiguous polygon shapefile, I'm needing a polygon vertex coordinate file in a format like this as input to a legacy program:

```
polygon1name, AUTO
  -120.408750    34.591250
  -120.398313    34.591250
  -120.396250    34.593313
  -120.396250    34.593354
END
polygon2name, AUTO
  -120.423354    34.641250
  -120.423313    34.641250
  -120.421250    35.643313
  -120.421250    35.647521
END
```

From a sample file it looks like the legacy program expects the pairs in a counter-clockwise drawing order. Here's a start with North Carolina counties as an example. I'm hoping for help in both how to export the XY pairs and to include the `, AUTO` and `END` pieces.

```
library(tidyverse) #for the %>% pipes and transmute()
library(sf) #for st_read()
library(rmapshaper) #for ms_simplify()

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%
      transmute(NAME, geometry) %>% #keeps just the county column for simplicity
      ms_simplify(keep = 0.01) #reduces the number of vertices for simplicity
plot(nc)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: You can get started by nesting the data on `NAME`, then adding something like `mutate(coords = map(data, st_coordinates))`. As for the counter-clockwise sorting, I don't know, which is why I don't have enough to flesh out into a complete answer

Comment: thank you @camille

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about the counter-clockwise order of coordinates, but this answers the output-format part of your question.

```
#extract coordinates from sf
coord    <- st_coordinates(nc) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  group_by( L3 ) %>% 
  mutate(L4 = row_number() )

#extract data from sf
polygons <- st_drop_geometry(nc) %>% 
  mutate( NAME = as.character( NAME ) ) %>%
  rownames_to_column( var = "id" ) %>% 
  mutate( id = as.numeric(id) ) %>%
  #join coordinates
  left_join( coord, by = c("id" = "L3") )

#split polygons-dataframe to list
l <- split( polygons, f = polygons$id )

#extract text needed from each polygon
result <- lapply( l, function(x) {
  paste0 ( paste0( unique( x$NAME ), ", AUTO\n" ),
           paste0( "  ", x$X, "    ", x$Y, collapse = "\n" ),
           "\nEND" )
})

#unlist and write lines
writeLines( unlist(result) )

# Ashe, AUTO
# -81.4727554    36.2343559
# -81.7410736    36.3917847
# -81.6699982    36.5896492
# -81.3452988    36.5728645
# -81.2398911    36.3653641
# -81.4727554    36.2343559
# END
# Alleghany, AUTO
# -81.2398911    36.3653641
# -81.3452988    36.5728645
# -80.9034424    36.5652122
# -80.9563904    36.4037971
# -81.2398911    36.3653641
# END
# Surry, AUTO
# -80.4563446    36.2425575
# -80.874382    36.2338829
```

**update**

For the counter-clockwise part: take a look at the `check_ring_dir` argument of `sf::st_read()`.

> check_ring_dir
>   logical; if TRUE, polygon ring directions are checked
>   and if necessary corrected (when seen from above: exterior ring
>   counter clockwise, holes clockwise)

Comment: updated with information about clockwise/anti-clockwise argument in st_read()

Comment: thank you much @Wimpel! New to `st_coordinates()`, scratching my head why `st_coordinates(my_sf_file)` produces L1 and L2 but not an L3 column?  `my_sf_file <- readOGR(".", "myshapefile) %>% st_as_sf() %>% transmute(Name, geometry)` makes what looks like to me the identical format as `nc`..

Comment: update - I think I see why, `my_sf_file` is tagged with `POLYGON` and not `MULTIPOLYGON`..

Comment: update - indeed - just needed to use `st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")`